# Setting up database for 'business_owners' and 'customers'

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I'm setting up a database that will have 'business_owners' and 'customers'.  I could set this up in a couple days but wanted to see what your opinion is on best practice.

I could have two tables, 'business_owners' and 'customers', each with name, email etc.  or...

I could do one table 'Users' and have a user_type as 'business_owner' or 'customer' and just use that type to determine what to show.

I'm thinking the second option is best, any feedback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Rule of thumb:

If you have more than one table with identical (or near identical) columns, they should be condensed into a single table.  Use a type code/etc to distinguish between as necessary, and work out the business rules for columns that depend on the type code.

### Answer:

The second option is the best approach.  It's the most scalable, and will be the easiest to work with if you ever need to use resultsets that include both business owners & customers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the difference between the two types, if they share exactly the same attributes aside from their role as either a 'user' or 'business owner' I would suggest going for the second option to avoid overkill in terms of having identical columns in 2 separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

How would you model this in an object model?  Would you set up a single superclass, call it "stakeholders", that captures the properties of both business-owners and customers?  Would you then set up specialized subclasses, "business-owner" and "customer" that extend the definition of  stakeholders?  If so, read on.

Your case looks like an instance of the Gen-Spec design pattern.  Gen-spec is familiar to object oriented programmers through the superclass-subclass hierarchy.  Unfortunately, introductions to relational database design tend to skip over how to design tables for the Gen-Spec situation.  Fortunately, it’s well understood.  A web search on “Relational database generalization specialization” will yield several articles on the subject.  Some of  your hits will be previous questions here on SO.  Here is one article that discusses Gen-Spec in terms of [Object Relational Mapping](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html).

The trick is in the way the PK for the subclass (specialized) tables gets assigned.  It’s not generated by some sort of autonumber feature.  Instead, it’s a copy of the PK in the superclass (generalized) table, and is therefore an FK reference to it.

Thus, if the case were vehicles, trucks and sedans, every truck or sedan would have an entry in the vehicles table, trucks would also have an entry in the trucks table, with a PK that’s a copy of the corresponding PK in the vehicles table.  Similarly for sedans and the sedan table.  It’s easy to figure out whether a vehicle is a truck or a sedan by just doing joins, and you usually want to join the data in that kind of query anyway.